# how can i sort an protected sheet using node package exceljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

I would like to be able to **sort** the sheet columns even if the cells are **locked**, but asoon as i try and sort a column it gives me an error message: '*Protected cells can not be modified*'

So I know the protect works, but the option (`{ sort: true }`) im passing is not?

I am not sure why I cant get it working, if its even possible but it seems via documentation that it can be an option to use.[[docs]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#sheet-protection)

So my current code setup is as this:

```js
let workbook = new excel.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Items')
await worksheet.protect('', { sort: true })

// after this i add rows and data to the cells
```